# Why do we assume the set of all sets that do not contain themselves exists?

Tags: set-theory, paradoxes

It seems to me that the set of all sets that do not contain themselves is very similar to the set
\begin{equation}
X = \{x | \ x \not\in X\}
\end{equation}
which is again very similar to the number $x$ such that
\begin{equation}
x\neq x
\end{equation}
For this number $x$ we simply state,
\begin{equation}
\mathrel{\nexists} x \in \mathbb{R} : x\neq x
\end{equation}
Why isn't the same done in the case of sets?
\begin{equation}
\mathrel{\nexists} X : X = \{x | \ x \not\in X\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathrel{\nexists} X : X \text{ contains all the sets that do not contain themselves}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do!  Assuming the existence of such a set, we can reach a contradiction.  This proves that no such set exists.  So, it is a theorem of set theory that there does not exist a set of all sets that do not contain themselves.

The problem (in set theory with unrestricted comprehension) is, it is *also* a theorem that such a set does exist.  Namely, the unrestricted comprehension axiom says that for any property $P$, there exists a set whose elements are exactly the sets that satisfy $P$.  In particular, if $P(x)$ is $x\not\in x$, this means that there is a set $\{x:x\not\in x\}$.

So, it is both a theorem that $\{x:x\not\in x\}$ does not exist and a theorem that it does exist.  This is a contradiction which makes set theory with unrestricted comprehension inconsistent.

In modern set theory, though, the axiom of unrestricted comprehension is not accepted (since it leads to a contradiction!).  So, Russell's paradox becomes simply a theorem that $\{x:x\not\in x\}$ does not exist, not an actual paradox.